# how show year for a techreport for plainnat bibliographystyle

Tags: bibtex

I want to put in my references a reference to a iso norm. So in my bibliography I have

```
@techreport{ISO25178,
type = {Standard},
key = {ISO 25178--2:2012},
month = {apr},
year = {2012},
title = {Spécification géométrique des produits (GPS) -- État de surface: Surfacique -- Partie 2: Termes, définitions et paramètres d'états de surface},
volume = {2012},
address = {Geneva, CH},
institution = {International Organization for Standardization}
}
```

When I do the citation I have no date in the citation. The result is : ISO 25178--2:2012()

How to have the date for a techreport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `author` instead of `key`; note the double braces for a “corporate author”.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{ISO25178,
type = {Standard},
key = {ISO 25178--2:2012},
month = {apr},
year = {2012},
title = {Spécification géométrique des produits (GPS) -- 
         État de surface: Surfacique -- Partie 2: Termes, 
         définitions et paramètres d'états de surface},
volume = {2012},
address = {Geneva, CH},
institution = {International Organization for Standardization}
}
@techreport{ISO25178-x,
type = {Standard},
author = {{ISO 25178--2:2012}},
month = {apr},
year = {2012},
title = {Spécification géométrique des produits (GPS) -- 
         État de surface: Surfacique -- Partie 2: Termes, 
         définitions et paramètres d'états de surface},
volume = {2012},
address = {Geneva, CH},
institution = {International Organization for Standardization}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\verb|\citet|: \citet{ISO25178} --- \verb|\citep|: \citep{ISO25178}

\verb|\citet|: \citet{ISO25178-x} --- \verb|\citep|: \citep{ISO25178-x}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]